# Как сделать единый шаблон для страниц?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, css

Делаю небольшой сайт состоящий не более чем из 10 страничек на html+css+js+jquery,
других технологий пока что не знаю.
Встал вопрос, если допустим я сделал изменение в одном документе, ну к примеру поменял логотип, как сделать изменения во всех других файлах, не внося изменения в каждый файл?
что необходимо знать для осуществления этого?

Comment: как минимум надо иметь сервер хоть на php хоть на node и потом использовать [includeHTML](https://github.com/xmoonlight/includeHTML) или чуть чуть изучить vue так как там компоненты стандартная процедура, можно использовать [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp) но это тоже на сервере , но самое лёгкое и просто это php

Comment: можно так же использовать [многострочные литералы](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings#%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8B) но это не будет работать в IE11 и почти во всех мобильных браузерах, но современные браузеры поддерживают

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1) Простое [SPA](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Можно сделать простое [SPA](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5), которое получает через AJAX страницы исходя из `location.hash` в url и делает единый шаблон.

Сделал для вас очень простой пример, скачать [ЗДЕСЬ](https://github.com/iliyaZelenko/v-tooltip/releases/download/untagged-3730fe0a26c8e5ef9150/VanillaSpaDemo.rar). Также там можно делать сколько угодно шаблонов и указывать какой странице какой принадлежит.

Однако, поскольку spa использует AJAX для динамической загрузки представлений, для локальной разработки Вам необходимо настроить локальный сервер.

Самый простой способ сделать это - глобальная установка http-сервера с использованием npm или yarn: `npm install -g http-server`

Затем запустите http-сервер в вашем кодовом каталоге и откройте свой браузер на localhost: 8080

```
cd /path/to/project/
http-server -o
```

## 2) [Server Side Includes](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSI_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5))

Если ваш сервер HTTP (сервер [apache 2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/ssi.html) и [IIS](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/eced0b89-e052-42ff-baa8-751dd191c3b5.mspx?mfr=true)) поддерживает [Server Side Includes](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSI_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)), вы можете легко вставлять другой файл HTML:

```
<!--#include file="header.html"-->

Ваш контент

<!--#include file="footer.html"-->
```

нет необходимости в серверном языке, просто HTML

## 3) PHP

Можно разделить шаблон по нескольким частям: `header.php` и `footer.php`, `head-tag-contents.php` и в этих файлах ставите свой хтмл код который повторяется на страницах.

Теперь можно создавать страницы в таком виде:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- чтобы не повторять одинаковый код в head -->
    <?php include("includes/head-tag-contents.php");?>
</head>
<body>

<?php include("includes/header.php");?>

<div id="main-content">
    <p>Мой супер контен</p>
</div>

<?php include("includes/footer.php");?>

</body>
</html>

?>
```

Есть много статей на эту тему, тут не нужно особо знать PHP.

Answer (score 3):

Можно как вариант подклюить компонент на каждую страницу через PHP, простая функция include '/path', еще как вариант использовать PUG, но там нужен Nodejs и к примеру Gulp